# Reverse match not found in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I broke something. The error reads: Reverse for 'wiki_article_detail' with arguments '(u'',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. I don't know where the 'u' came from in arguments. here is the model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    """Represents a wiki article"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Publish?")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedArticlesManager()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('wiki_article_detail', (), { 'slug': self.slug })
```

The template is:

```
<body>

{% if object_list %}

    <h2 class="articlePageTitle">All Articles</h2>
    <h3>Filter by country</h3>
    <h3>Filter by category</h3>

    <ul>
        {% for article in object_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url wiki_article_detail article.slug %}">{{ article.title }}</a>
        </li>
{% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% else %}
    <h2>No articles have been published yet.</h2>
{% endif %}

    <a href="{% url wiki_article_add %}">Create new article</a

</body>
```

the debugger is indicating the error in this line:

```
<a href="{% url wiki_article_detail article.slug %}">{{ article.title }}</a>
```

This was all working fine before, I had some db problems and had to recreate the db file, but there wasn't much in there. But now, I can write an article and view it, but I can't get to the /all list.

urls.py snippet:

```
 url(r'^all/$',
        'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list',
       {
            'queryset': Article.published.all(),
        },
        name='wiki_article_index'),
```

the urls.py snippet that is referenced in the error:

```
url(r'^article/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', 
        'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail',
        {
            'queryset': Article.objects.all(),
        },
        name='wiki_article_detail'),
```

Comment: Please post the appropriate snippet from your `urls.py`

Comment: added urls.py snippet

Comment: By the way, the 'u' before a string in Python just means that it's a unicode string - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

Comment: Yeah, I just found that too.Thanks.

Comment: I changed article.slug in the template tag to article.title and it works. I may leave it for now, but the slug thing is bothering me.

Comment: It seems that for one entry, the slug field didn't get written, and it broke the whole thing. I removed the bad entry from the db and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
{{ article.title }}